# How to use Flask in Google Colaboratory Python Notebook?

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory

I am trying to build a website using Flask, in a Google Colab Python notebook. However, running a regular Flask code that works on a regular Python, fails to work on Google Colab. I need code that will work it out please.. :)

Comment: you're likely running into CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) limitations, or Flask magic stuff that doesn't work in a notebook context.

Comment: So is there a different way to build web frameworks using Python Notebooks in Google Colab?

Answer (score 17):

The server code:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn(socket.gethostname())))

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

import threading
threading.Thread(target=app.run, kwargs={'host':'0.0.0.0','port':80}).start()
```

Client code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://172.28.0.2/")
print(r.status_code)
print(r.encoding)
print(r.apparent_encoding)
print(r.text)
```

To restart Flask you may click menu:  runtime->restart runtime

Share link [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ocoD0B0h2F8HhwWz9j9Td4uhvoTk_Um2) :

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to send 'Control-C' to the server without doing `restart runtime`?

Answer (score 9):

```
!pip install flask-ngrok


from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  # Start ngrok when app is run

# for / root, return Hello Word
@app.route("/")
def root():
    url = request.method
    return f"Hello World! {url}"

app.run()
```

https://medium.com/@kshitijvijay271199/flask-on-google-colab-f6525986797b

Answer (score 1):

The server side code AKA: backend

```
from flask import Flask
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

threading.Thread(target=app.run, kwargs={'host':'0.0.0.0','port':6060}).start()
```

Rendering the server inside the colab

```
import IPython.display

def display(port, height):
    shell = """
        (async () => {
            const url = await google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(%PORT%, {"cache": true});
            const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.src = url;
            iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            iframe.setAttribute('height', '%HEIGHT%');
            iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        })();
    """
    replacements = [
        ("%PORT%", "%d" % port),
        ("%HEIGHT%", "%d" % height),
    ]
    for (k, v) in replacements:
        shell = shell.replace(k, v)

    script = IPython.display.Javascript(shell)
    IPython.display.display(script)

display(6060, 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

run_with_ngrok(app)  
@app.route("/")

def home():
    return f"Running Flask on Google Colab!"

app.run()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

## Install Additional Packages in Google Colab

```bash
!pip install flask-ngrok
!pip install pyngrok==4.1.1
```

In order to use `flask-ngrok` within the code, and to facilitate the use of ngrok, you need to obtain an authentication token from the [ngrok website](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken). After obtaining the token, run the following command:

```bash
!ngrok authtoken <ngrok-token>
```

Now, you can write your code in a Colab cell. Here's an example using Flask with ngrok:

```py
# flask_ngrok_example.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  # Start ngrok when app is run

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When you run the code, you will see output similar to the following:

```bash
 * Serving Flask app '__main__'
 * Debug mode: off
INFO:werkzeug:WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
INFO:werkzeug:Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Running on http://36ed-35-237-206-208.ngrok-free.app
 * Traffic stats available on http://127.0.0.1:4040
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2023 11:54:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2023 11:54:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Congratulations! You have successfully run Flask in Google Colab.